# Swift completion handeler issue

Tags: json, swift, asynchronous

I am trying to figure out this completion handler, but I just cant get my head around it. I have this program that I am trying to download a json file and parse it. It all works fine but I want the UI to update after the file has been download and parsed. I have to push the button twice to get it to work. I know why this is happening. The code is working async style and just goes to update the UI with nothing. How can I get it to wait for the json to finish parsing and downloading.
Thank you for any help and tips on this

This is what I have so far:

```
 @IBAction func testerClick(sender: AnyObject) {


    print("Button pushed")

    print("Downloading the json file")
    downlaodPromoData(promoUrl, myUser: myUserName, myPass: myPassword)



}

func parsePromoJson(json : String)
{
    //parse the json file
    if let data = downloadJson.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
        let json = JSON(data: data)
        for item in json[].arrayValue {
            pictures.append(item["picture"].stringValue)
        }
        for item in json[].arrayValue{
            path.append(item["path"].stringValue)
        }
        for item in json[].arrayValue{
            label.append(item["label"].stringValue)
        }
    }
    // Loop over the array with a for-loop.
    for i in 0 ..< pictures.count {
        uiResultsTextField.text.appendContentsOf("Picture: " + pictures[i] + "\n" + "Path: " + path[i] + "\n" + "Label: " + label[i] + "\n")
    }

}

func downlaodPromoData(myUrl : String, myUser : String, myPass : String)
{
    Alamofire.request(.GET, myUrl)
        .authenticate(user: myUser, password: myPass)
        .validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
        .responseString { response in
            print("Success: \(response.result.isSuccess)")
            print("Response String: \(response.result.value)")

            self.downloadJson = response.result.value!

            /*
             .response {(request, response, data, error) in
             print(response)
             print(data)
             print(request)
             */
        }.responseJSON { response in
            print("Response JSON: \(response.result.value)")
    }

    print("Calling parser")
    parsePromoJson(downloadJson)
}
```

Comment: try moving the call to `parsePromoJson()` inside the `.responseString` callback, just after the line `self.downloadJson = response.result.value!'

Comment: Thank you your suggestion was right. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're calling the parsePromoJson immediately after the request. Move the parsePromoJson call to inside the responseString block of the Alamofire request.

Comment: Worked like a charm. I had that section of code all over the place just not right under the right spot. Thank you a lot